# Selenium Email - Old emailable-report.html generated on every test execution

Tags: email, selenium-webdriver, email-attachments

Old emailable-report generates after testcase execution in testng.
Here is the code for your reference.

```
    public void EmailFunction() {
        try {
            EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
            attachment.setPath(".\\test-output\\emailable-report.html");
            attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
            attachment.setDescription("Test Report Logs");
            attachment.setName("Report.html");

            // Create the email message
            MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
            email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
            email.setSmtpPort(587);
            email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(MyEmail, MyPassword));
            email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
            email.setFrom(MyEmail, "Faizan Mamji");
            email.addCc("abc@test.com");
            email.setSubject("Report Logs");
            email.setMsg("Please find attached logs!");
            email.addTo(MyEmail, "Faizan Mamji");

            // add the attachment
            email.attach(attachment);

            // send the email
            email.send();
        }

        catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.getMessage();
            Assert.fail("Email failed to send");
        }
    }

@AfterTest
    public void afterTest() {
        TestExecutionEmail ObjEmail= new TestExecutionEmail(maindriver);
        maindriver.quit();
        ObjEmail.EmailFunction();
    }
```

Please guide how to generate updated report after every complete test execution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simply replace the @AfterTest with @AfterSuite annotation as you need to trigger the email code at the very end of the execution.

Comment: Try adding some wait as well.

Comment: Adding wait also does not help.